# using typeof operator in string interpolation to check data type of variable when running the code output is not coming correct

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, typeof

```js
let num = 1
let st = 'data'
console.log(typeof `${num}`, typeof `${st}`)
```

the output of the first variable should be number but it's printing string when I am using string interpolation `` console.log(typeof `${num}`) `` it's printing string, but when I am writing `console.log(typeof num)` it's printing number
can someone plz expalin why

Comment: It's not clear what you expect **string interpolation** to return if not a string?!

Answer (score 1):

The result of string interpolation (called a [*template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) is by definition a string, so that's what `typeof` returns. The type of the original expression that was interpolated is not available. Usually you're not just putting one expression into the template, there will be multiple expression and/or other text, so it wouldn't even be meaningful for the type to come from the interpolated expression. E.g. if you did

```
console.log(typeof `num = ${num}, st = ${st}`);
```

why would you expect the result to be related to the types of `num` or `st`?

Answer (score 1):

this is probably what you want:

```js
let num = 1
let st = 'data'
console.log(`typeof num = ${typeof num}, typeof st = ${typeof st}`)
```

`typeof` must be followed directly with the variable

template literal always return string and call `.toString()` method on each variable used in it in `${}` thats why after interpolation it is always the string

Answer (score -2):

The backtick converts your number into a string. If you are deadset on using backticks, you can **implicitly cast** it back to a number like so:

```
console.log(typeof +`${num}`);
```

One of the few use cases I'd see for this is if you got number variables as different digits. Example:

```
// Compose the number "57" and print the type
const tensDigit = 5;
const onesDigit = 7;
console.log(typeof +`${tensDigit}${onesDigit}`)
```